# Web application for project management using SVN

Tags: jakarta-ee, svn, web-applications

I started developing a web application (Java EE) for project management. There are many documents to share and I'd like to integrate SVN into my application

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Subversion is an open source project with open protocols.  There are many examples of applications that integrate with Subversion, including most commonly IDE's like Eclipse or Visual Studio.

SVNKit provides an open source library for integrating SVN into your application

> SVNKit brings Subversion closer to the Java world! SVNKit is a pure Java toolkit - it implements all Subversion features and provides APIs to work with Subversion working copies, access and manipulate Subversion repositories - everything within your Java application.

http://svnkit.com/

Comment: can someone send a tutorial or smthing that help me